# Loop + Add to Array on Blur

Tags: jquery

I am having a little bit of difficulty understanding how to do this.  However here it goes.

There are a bunch of input fields that user can add to.

I need to write a jQuery script without adding anything to the markup of the HTML explicitly.

1. Find all elements with a class of `inputAmt`
2. If user blurs form input field the jQuery script would trigger.
3. Add all the value to find the total.
4. If user subtracts anything it needs to reflect the total.

Little complicated for me I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please add some code, try to be more accurate. Your current question does not meet SO standards.

Comment: As far as the HTML markup is concerned here is a sample code for it:

<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="txtr">
<input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something"> 
</td>
<td class="txtr">
<input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something1"> 
</td>
<td class="txtr">
<input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something2"> 
</td>
<td class="txtr">
<input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something3"> 
</td>
<td class="txtr">
<input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something4"> 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: I tried writing some code that accesses the element and it's value and that seems to work just need to figure out how to loop through it and add an event handler which checks for the blur functionality.

var allInputValues = $.makeArray($('.inputAmt').val());

This grabs the first occurrence of input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets get all elements with `inputAmt` class.

```
var elements = $('.inputAmt');
```

now lets create a function that adds their values

```
function addElementValues(){
   var sum = 0;
   elements.each(function(){
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      // when this.value is empty or non numeric the parseFloat returns NaN (Not A Number)
      // so you might want to do sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
      // to ignore the NaN values
   });
   // do something with the sum value here
   // like display it on some element
}
```

finally lets use this function when any field is blurred

```
elements.on('blur', addElementValues);
```

---

Full working example

```js
var elements = $('.inputAmt');

function addElementValues() {
  var sum = 0;
  elements.each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
  });
  // do something with the sum value here
  // like display it on some element
  $('#total').text( sum );
}

elements.on('blur', addElementValues);
```

```css
.w70 {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="txtr">
        <input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something">
      </td>
      <td class="txtr">
        <input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something1">
      </td>
      <td class="txtr">
        <input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something2">
      </td>
      <td class="txtr">
        <input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something3">
      </td>
      <td class="txtr">
        <input type="text" class="inputAmt w70" name="something4">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much this really helped a lot with me understand exactly how to get this done.  Thanks soo much again.