# jquery input field array validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page where a user can add new fields to the form by clicking a button. I'm trying to perform validation on each of the fields, including the ones the user adds by clicking the button. When I perform the validation, it just checks the initial field and not the remainder. The validation I'm doing is making sure that the user exists in active directory (AD). So far, the AD validation works (I use it on multiple pages) but it does not perform the check on each of the fields. I've tried a few things and I've posted those below as well. I'm not that great at javascript, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious question.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var elements = $('#userID');
function getvalues(){
    var inps = document.getElementsByName('userID[]');
    for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
        var inp=inps[i];
        $.post("../config/getDisplayName.php",{requester: inp.value}, function(data, status){
            $("#ownerUnameDisplayName").append(data);
            $("#ownerUnameDisplayName").append("<br>");
        });
    }
}
function addElementValues(){
    var sum = 0;
    elements.each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    getvalues();
}
elements.on('blur', addElementValues);
# This is the portion of the script that adds the additional fields. This works as expected.
$("#addPerson").click(function(){
    $("<input name='userID[]' id='userID' class='w3-input w3-border entryField' type='text' placeholder='User ID' required>").appendTo("#contactCardData");
    $("<input name='lastname[]' class='w3-input w3-border entryField' type='text' placeholder='Last Name' required>").appendTo("#contactCardData");
    $("<input name='firstname[]' class='w3-input w3-border entryField' type='text' placeholder='First Name' required>").appendTo("#contactCardData");
    $("<input name='externalAddress[]' class='w3-input w3-border entryField' type='text' placeholder='Email/Phone Number' required>").appendTo("#contactCardData");
});
});
</script>
```

Another thing I tried:

```
var elements = $('#userID');
function getvalues(){
    var inps = document.getElementsByName('userID[]');
    for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
        var inp=inps[i];
        $.post("../config/getDisplayName.php",{requester: inp.value}, function(data, status){
            $("#ownerUnameDisplayName").append(data);
            $("#ownerUnameDisplayName").append("<br>");
        });
    }
}
var userField = $("input[name='userID[]']");
userField.blur(function(){
    userField.each(function(){
        getvalues();
        var ownerUname = $(this).val();
        
    });
});
```

Here are my sources:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148865/loop-add-to-array-on-blur
http://jsfiddle.net/5jd8N/1/
```

I don't have a lot of sources as I was trying a few different things that I thought would work.

Like I said above, I've tried the code above but it only effects the first field. I need to be able to validate every field after the "Add Person" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements.on('blur', addElementValues);
```

This line is only called on page load. Adding a new input will not automatically bind `addElementValues` to the `blur` event. You will have to explicitly bind it again whenever you add a new input, either by unbinding all and rebinding all, or binding just to the new one.

Example:

```
...append("<input data='new' ...>");
$("input[data=new]").removeAttr("data").on("blur", addElementValues);
```